# It is a lot of particles "of"

Tags: prepositions, translation, repetition

My native language is russian, and I'm trying to translate RU>EN some techical text.
I've found one thing: a lot of "of".

Let's look: "Определение цветов данного набора паллитр" > "Determination of colors of this set of palettes".

Am I doing something wrong, or this is language's specific thing?

Comment: This isn't the right place for translation requests or writing style help. Are you asking if there is a limit on the number of "of"s in a row? If so, no, there isn't.

Comment: I think this would be on-topic at [English.SE] or [ELL.SE]. It's essentially asking if your translation is natural.

Answer (score 4):

No, nothing wrong --- that's English for you.  But you can use stylistic maneuvers to reduce the tiring "of" repetition.  "Determination of colors of this set of palettes" could be rephrased "Color determination for this palette set", where I've turned two "of" constructions into the compound nouns "color determination" and "palette set", and changed an "of" into a "for".

Comment: Greg, agreed.  It must be frustrating for learners *of* English to be told that 'of' is one of the ways of indicating possession, only to find that it sometimes indicates an object.